# How to modify object in complex array?

Tags: javascript

I have such a data structure:

```
data: [
       {
         current: true,
         id: "3d6266501370d",
         name: "Option",
         items: [
                     {
                       hidden: false,
                       id: "ed716c12bf8f3",
                       data: "ffff",
                      }
                    ],
         selected_queries:[
                        {
                          id: 67896,
                          data: "ff",

                       }
          ]
        },    
     ]
```

and I need to edit just hidden filed of every object, other values I need to keep as it is. I created such a code:

```
export const editField = (id, status) => {
  return new Promise((res) => {
    const data = getData();
    const newData = data.map(dataItem => {
      if (dataItem.current) {
        const newDataItem = dataItem.items.map(item => {
          if (item.id === id) {
              return Object.assign({}, item, {
                ...item,
                hidden: status,
              });
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        })
        return newDataItem;
      } else {
        return dataItem;
      }
    })
    res(newData);
  });
}
```

but I get new object whch has null. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What is `getData()`? Is it asynchronous?

Comment: yes, it returns data. It works correctly

Comment: If `const data = getData(); const newData = data.map(...)` works then `getData()` cannot be asynchronous.

Comment: do you get `id`, and `status` arguments correctly?

Comment: yes, I get them correctly

Comment: your hidden property is null or new object?

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `data = getData()` (per Marks's comment) it is assigning `data = null` until `getData()` returns. Only then is it getting updated. So `newData = data.map...` is being run on nothing. You could assign a callback on `getData`:

```
function getData(cb){
    data = get the data..
    cb(data)
}

//Then use it like:

const data = getData(function(data){
    newData = data.map...
});
```

Comment: I get data before map()

Comment: Will you include this output in your question: `data = getData(); console.log(data); newData = data.map...`

Answer (score 0):

You could transform **getData()** in a Promise too, something like:

```
var promiseData = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  resolve(getData());
});

promiseData.then(function(data) {
  // THE REST OF YOUR CODE USING "data"
}).catch(function(error){
  console.error(error);
});
```

Then you'll be sure that you got the data you needed.